# How can I parse a date as week-year in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I need to select two sets of data - one from last week and one from the same week last year.

The way I see this working is by extracting the week number, so

```sql
SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM DATE_FIELD)
```

I'm then getting the year value of last year according to last Monday, like so

```sql
SELECT DATE_SUB(
                DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY), WEEK(MONDAY)), 
               INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

I've managed to concatenate these values together so that they represent a date in the format of %Y-%W.  eg. `2019-03`

However, using the `PARSE_DATE()` function doesn't seem to work for parsing year-week in BigQuery. I've tried a number of combinations with static strings, e.g:

```sql
SELECT PARSE_DATE("%Y-%W", '2020-53'),
       PARSE_DATE("%Y-%W", '2019-01'),
       PARSE_DATE("%Y-%W", '2018-00')
```

No matter the input, the date always comes out as January 1st on the year specified

```
Row f0_ f1_ f2_ 
1   
2020-01-01
2019-01-01
2018-01-01
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do? Sample input/output rows will help us answer your question.  `PARSE_DATE()` returns a `DATE` type, so don't be surprised that they are returning a date.  As for why they are returning January 1, if the function returns a date, and you aren't specifying the month or day, it will return 01 and 01, aka January 1.

Comment: I'm looking to derive exactly what the week was 1 year ago.  This week is week 5 (commencing 3rd Feb 2020), so I would want to get week 5 from 2019 to compare against.  In principle, I would have thought that the best way to do this is to get that week number (5) as an integer and change the year value to 2020 subtract 1.  I've achieved this as a string, but parsing it is my issue.

Answer (score -1):

About your question on how to pass a date in BigQuery using the format *YEAR-WEEK*, I would advise you to use the function [FORMAT_DATE()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#format_date).

This function uses two parameters. The first one must be a *STRING*, with this parameter you select how your date will be displayed. You can follow [this dictionary](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#supported_format_elements_for_date) to help you choose the one which suits you the best. In your case, I would use either "%Y-%W" or "%Y-%V". According to the documentation:

> %V: The ISO 8601 week number of the year (Monday as the first day of
>   the week) as a decimal number (01-53). If the week containing January
>   1 has four or more days in the new year, then it is week 1; otherwise
>   it is week 53 of the previous year, and the next week is week 1.
>
> %W: The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week)
>   as a decimal number (00-53).

The second parameter must be in a *DATE* format.

Below there is an example of the syntax with with dummy data:

```
with a as (
select '2019-01-01' as date union all 
select '2020-10-21' as date union all
select '2018-08-15' as date 
order by date
)
select  format_date("%Y-%W", cast(date as date)) as date_w,
        format_date("%Y-%V", cast(date as date)) as date_v 
from a
```

Notice that I used [CAST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules) function to convert a string to date format.And the output is:

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: My problem is the reverse I'm afraid; I'm unable to convert dates that have already been formatted as Week-year back into normal date values.  Thanks for your answer though, it is helpful

Comment: @tonneofash, if you have any issues implementing it I may be able to help.